# Best way to check data is boolean or not

Tags: java, boolean

I need to find in java if the content of a String variable is boolean or not.
I am getting "True" or "False" or "garbage" as String.

Looking for a way to return true when data is either "True" or "False" & false when any "other value".

The code I wrote:

```
    Boolean checkBoolean(String val){
        boolean result;
        switch(val){
        case "true":
        result =true;
        break;
        case "false":
        result =true;
        break;
        default:
            result = false;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Did you write any code?

Comment: Yes please check edited question, sry for that

Comment: @newguy does case matter? That is, would "true" return true, but "True" would return false?

Comment: The 'datatype of a variable' is fixed at compile time, by the rules of the language. What your code is doing is inspecting the *content* of a `String`. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: @EJP, yes I am inspecting the contect of a String, Thanks for making it more clear. I've updated the question

Comment: It can be done the way I did, but I am asking if there's any other better way, maybe pre-build method that can be used?

Comment: What does 'pre-build method' mean?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming, you want TRUE if val is either TRUE or FALSE (ignoring cases).

```
boolean checkBoolean(String val){
    val = val.toLowerCase();
    return (val.equals("true") || val.equals("false"));
}
```

If on the other hand, you require the function to return true if the string is TRUE(ignoring cases) and false otherwise; use

```
Boolean boolean1 = Boolean.valueOf("true");
boolean boolean2 = Boolean.parseBoolean("true");
```

For the above methods, please check the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html).

Just a caveat for using Boolean instead of boolean.

- First one is Object and second one is primitive type.
- On first one, you will get more methods which will be useful.
- Second one is cheap considering memory expense.
  Now choose your way.

Comment: Thanks, your first solution is my answer.

Comment: Also, you can convert between them easily, so, you can preprocess some string, and after that work with primitive `boolean` if memory is crital. Same applies to `Integer` and `int` and other primitives.

Answer (score 1):

I would question the objective here. What you may really want to know is whether you received an acceptable form of `"true"` or not. In which case [`Boolean.parseBoolean()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html#parseBoolean-java.lang.String-) is exactly what you need.

Comment: Good call. This will also be case agnostic.

Comment: The object is to find if i got something that is boolean or not, if I use Boolean.parseBoolean("false") it will return false, but I want true here as it's a boolean value.

Comment: Got it from where? How does the problem arise? You can usually design your way around problems like this: for example, use a checkbox in the UI, not a string field.

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
public boolean getBool(String s) {
  return (s.equals("True") || s.equals("False"));
}
```

If you want to accept case-insensitiv e.g.: TrUe, fALSe,  ect use

```
s.equalsIgnoreCase("... ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the fact that case doesn't really matter, I would try the following code:

```
boolean checkBoolean(String val){
    if ("true".equalsIgnoreCase(val)) {
        return true;
    } else if ("false".equalsIgnoreCase(val)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

It's pretty similar to what you have above but is case agnostic. Let me know if I'm missing some hidden requirement here.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
 Boolean checkBoolean(String val){
    if(val.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("true"))
    {
       return true;
    }
    else if(val.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("false"))
       return true;
    else
       return false;
}
```

This way you don't have to declare a local boolean variable.

Trim allows you to send string with white spaces.

And IgnoreCase helps you to send strings with lower/upper case e.g. `TruE` or `faLSe`.

Answer (score 0):

you can do

```
public boolean isBooleanCheck(String s) {
    return (s.equalsIgnoreCase("true") || s.equalsIgnoreCase("false"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use regular expression of String.matches(string expression).

return val.matches("(?i)(true)|(false)");

the "(?i)" is for case insensitive.

Answer (score -1):

I think what you want to do can be done by doing this:

```
 return myBoolean instanceof Boolean;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String i = "true";
        boolean z = checkBoolean(i);
        System.out.println(z);
    }

    public static boolean checkBoolean(String i){
        if(i.equalsIgnoreCase("true")||i.equalsIgnoreCase("false")){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Now it doesn't even compile.

Comment: Sorry, the variable i should've been String type, i corrected it @EJP

Answer (score -2):

The data type `boolean` is used to contain values for `true` or `false`. So if you declare a variable as a `boolean` it will contain either `true` or `false`. You can use that result according to your requirements. For example:

```
boolean i = true;
boolean u = false;
```

Comment: the OP is trying to parse an input string. check the provide method signature.